# User Interface using JQuery to auto scroll to a window section

Tags: jquery, scroll

I created a HTML 5 app page that fits the Android Tab 2 screen perfectly. Each section is exactly the size of the viewport. It scrolls top to bottom with 5 total sections.

I want to use Jquery to have the browser scroll to the top of the section automatically if the user finds themselves between two sections.

I see an example for what I'd like to do here: 
http://www.twenty8twelve.com/

See how if you are 30 pixels(or whatever) down in a section, after a second, the area(section) animates to the top of the section.

Answer (score 1):

They are using some custom jScroll mojo to accomplish the effect. I would suggest using a simple plugin like this to simulate that behavior.

Example of the effect:
http://nick-jonas.github.com/windows/

The github repo: https://github.com/nick-jonas/nick-jonas.github.com/tree/master/windows

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a library the fullpage.js library I created using the option `autoScrolling:false` to create a normal scroll instead of the automatic one.

[Example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html)

By default fullpage.js uses the option `fitToSection:true` that will create the effect you are looking for.

Additionally you will be able to make use of some other features such as the use of linkable anchors in the URL, callbacks, menus, navigation bullets...etc.